# How to create lists given a number without writing everything line by line?

Tags: python

Say there is a variable that finds a number of objects, and empty lists have to be created for each object.
For example:

```
objectNum = 4
a = [ ]
b = [ ]
c = [ ]
d = [ ]
```

Or with any other number, and those lists have to be named by alphabet. How can this be done?

I tried using globals() function, but that was applicable to variables, not lists

Comment: Do they really have to be variables? Variables that you don't know in advance, well, you don't know to use them later either. Normally one uses a python dictionary for this. `data = {"a": [], "b":[], ...}`.

Comment: @tdelaney So this dictionary of lists can be accessed and used just as a regular list written?

Comment: @Flerken not accessing the lists is a little different from regular lists, but using them would be the same because they are lists https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: Similarly. Suppose you had 4 keys like the variables shown. If you wanted to append to one, it would be something like `data["a"].append("something")`. Or, if you got the variable name programatically, says its in the `foo` variable. Even though you don't know whether its a, b etc,,, you could do `data[foo].append("bar")`. Its hard to write an answer to this question because its not clear which of the thousand things you could do with a variable, you are interested in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want a variable number of variables that you don't know in advance, one usually uses a dictionary instead of adding them dynamically to the module namespace as a variable. If you didn't know you were going to add, say, "t", how would you know to use it later?

In your example, you want lower case letters up to some given value to reference lists. You could build a dict

```
import string

objectNum = 4
assert objectNum <= 26
data = {}
for i in range(objectNum):
    data[string.ascii_lower[i]] = []

# or more likey you'd write it...
data = {var:[] for var in string.ascii_lower[:objectNum]}
```

Now, instead of variable `a`, you have `data["a"]`. That seems like more typing in this example, but the idea is autogeneration.